# How to track website page views without thirdparty tools in apache

Tags: apache

I want to track page views without any third party tools in my website. In `ASP.NET` it have the [`global.aspx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178583%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) file. It's contain global events and when any given page access, it's fired.Are there any similarities to `PHP`?So if not,
I can create a single `PHP` script and include into every page to track visitors,but it's time wasting and unnecessary overhead.
Are there any **Application-Level Event Handlers** in php ?

**Any suggestions to do this task?**
I have doubt how Google do that by using single script file in one page.:

Example of unnecessary overhead when including single file to every php

```
www.mysite.com/index.php /* this one OK we can track in simple php script */
www.mysite.com/css /*- BUT this dir how do it ? */
```

> There's no php files,But I want to track that dir also.

Comment: You are looking for the "auto prepend file"  feature for the combination of php and a http server. Or maybe php's ``tick()`` feature.

Comment: Ive done similar, but using Symfony and creating a request listener. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html#request-events-checking-types

Comment: @arkascha  may be it's fine when I cannot find the better solution.Actually I want send an email when accessing my pages.But let say they access `www.mywebsite.com/css` path it's should be tracked.but there's no PHP file in that direcotry

Comment: An email _for every single request to your http server_? No, you do _not_ want that. If you want to track requests to all objects, not just pgp scripts, then why is the question tagged `php`? I guess in case of apache you are loking for request handlers then: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/handler.html

Comment: @arkascha When I used it for my site why because there is no heavy usages.

Comment: Yo never know what is gonna hit your server. What if a bot comes by? Seriously, that is what logging is for. Take a look at your servers log files.

Comment: @arkascha How to used `apache handlers` as a solution ?

Comment: There are a dozen apps that process the apache access file for stats. Awstats is a personal favourite

Comment: Well, by registering a handler without binding it to a specific file type. So a catch all, kind of.

Comment: @Dagon The OP specifically asked for a solution without 3rdparty code (whatever that _really_ means).

Comment: So write your own code to process the file

Comment: @Dagom Any how give me a perfect solution for identify if user arrive to my website and what page he had access ?

Comment: @arkascha  Any how please suggests  me a perfect solution for identify if user arrive to my website and what page he had access ?

Comment: "perfect solution" whats that? No third party why? There are many options you dismiss for no good reason

Comment: @Dagon OK fine any solution with third party tools,but i want to send email with each and every request .

Comment: that's crazy any bot could send you thousands of emails

Comment: @Dagon You don't worry with the visitors and how many emails will send.Because daily visitors less than 10.